# Slider CSS, jQuery and layout - my slider handle likes to fly away

Tags: jquery, css, html

https://www.radiumhosting.com/clients/nodecart.php

When sliding the handle to the right one node, the margin of div class='ui-slider' id='slider' changes from margin: 0; to margin: -60px 0 0; causing the div to move up. Before I started working on this, the nodes would move up also, but I added div style="height:60px;" to force them to stay in place. This is in the 4th line in the snippet below.

Does anyone have any creative ideas for keeping div id='slider' stationary?

```
                <div class="slider-background-repeat">
                <div class="slider-background-left">
                    <div class='slider-wrap'>
                    <div style="height:60px;">
                        <div class='ui-slider' id='slider'>
                          <div class='ui-slider-handle'></div>
                            <div class='handle-text nodes-1'></div>
                            <input class="text text" id="numNodes" name="numNodes" value="{$defaultNodes}" size="30" type="text" />

                        </div>

                     </div>   

                        <ul class='slider-nodes' id='slider-nodes'></ul>

                        <div id='nodesprev' onClick="MoveNodesBack()" ><img src="./modules/servers/vpsnet/assets/images/prev.png" border="0"></div>
                        <div id='nodesnext' onClick="MoveNodesForward()"><img src="./modules/servers/vpsnet/assets/images/next.png" border="0"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like line 20 of your CSS is the class that is added to your handle

```
#vps-net-slider .slider-wrap #slider.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle.active { background-position:-75px -20px;}
```

that class is added around line 597 of your slide.js file. I'm pretty sure that is what is causing your issue.

Comment: I checked those lines and even commented them out, but the handle still slides out of view.